# OrientDB installation of Raspberry Pi issues

Tags: java, debian, raspberry-pi, orientdb

I'm hitting some snags getting OrientDB installed on my Raspberry Pi and ran out of ideas from Googling.  I tried adding `-Dmemory.useUnsafe=false -Dstorage.compressionMethod=gzip` to the end of the last line of the /bin/server.sh but that didn't seem to help.

The server starts and I can access it over HTTP but the JVM crashes when I try to create a database or connect to the default database.  Any ideas?

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0xabf09054, pid=3075, tid=2878796912
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0-b132) (build 1.8.0-b132)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.0-b70 mixed mode linux-arm )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [snappy-1.1.0.1-d0822a9b-fe72-4159-a4b2-d57af0058267-libsnappyjava.so+0x1054]  _init+0x187
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before     starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00657ae0):  JavaThread "OrientDB HTTP Connection /192.168.8.111:2480<-/192.168.2.115:57404" daemon     [_thread_in_native, id=3102, stack$

siginfo:si_signo=SIGILL: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (ILL_ILLOPC), si_addr=0xabf09054
```

Comment: Are you compiling the source or using the pre-compiled download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raspberry Pi and OrientDB ... could not resist trying it out :)

For your information:

- Using Raspberry Pi model B (512MB)
- Using Raspbian 7.6 (with latest patches as of 2014-11-28)
- Using [Oracle Java 8 SE for ARM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-arm-downloads-2187472.html) **update 6** (so not the version from the Raspbian repo!)
- Using OrientDB 2.0-M3
- Set `MAXHEAP=-Xmx128m` in `server.sh`

With this configuration i am able to create / query / modify a database via HTTP without problems. OrientDB complains about the shortage of memory, but that is all:

> WARNING No enough physical memory available: 437MB (heap=123MB). Set
>   lower Heap and restart OrientDB. Now running with DISKCACHE=64MB

Comment: Have you tried the same config but compiling it from source?  The precompiled version I download runs fine but when I compile it I get the same error as the OP.

Comment: No, I have only tried the precompiled version. You compiled it on the ARM machine?

Comment: Yes using the Oracle Java 8 compiler (I assume ... displaying the help for it doesn't tell you much).

Comment: Thanks!  I updated to Java 1.8.0_08 and installed the OrientDB 2.0-M3 (precompiled linux) and it seems to be working on my Raspberry Pi B+.